# How to create realistic shampoo/gel shader with cycles

Tags: shaders

[image]

Hi! I'm trying to achieve pretty much exactly the attached result but I can't seem to get my material right. Any recommendations is highly appreciated!!

---

@luciano - thanks! Well - I know I'm relatively off with everything. The modeling obviously need some additional work. My issue is more the shading as of now. Not really sure how to achieve the gradient look with semi-translucent/transparency + real glossyness as if it has a watery coating basically. Well - as you can see I'm lost in translation, hehe.

[image]

---

[image]

@luciano - thanks! Well - I know I'm relatively off with everything. The modeling obviously need some additional work. My issue is more the shading as of now. Not really sure how to achieve the gradient look with semi-translucent/transparency + real glossyness as if it has a watery coating basically. Well - as you can see I'm lost in translation, hehe.

Comment: what have you tried? it would help to see where you're at with it

Comment: See below @Luciano !